# How set "text-decoration: line-through" style for a label that has inside an <input> element?

Tags: css, checkbox, styles, line-through

I have -

```
<label for="1640801145364"><input type="checkbox" value="foo" id="1640801145364" name="foo">foo</label>
```

I need to set "text-decoration: line-through" style (in file.css) for a label that has inside an  element.  I tried write next in file.css, but it doesn't helps me.

```
label>input[type=checkbox]:checked {
    text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS cannot 'go back upwards' in the way you would like to do here, so the checked status of the input cannot affect the overall label.

There are a few ways round this. You could just swap the input out of the label to be before it, but of course that would alter the look. Instead this snippet puts the contents of the label in a span element and then the state of the input can influence the styling of that as the new element is a following sibling.

```css
input:checked+* {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<label for="1640801145364">
<input type="checkbox" value="foo" id="1640801145364" name="foo">
  <span>foo</span>
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see your CSS, you thought that the *foo* text will be inside the input, **but not really** that's because: `<input>` don't need a closing tag so they can't inner *foo* text

so first a *foo* text in a `span` so with CSS we can easily select it

then I used a CSS COMBINATOR **`~`** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator

> you can write it with ALT126

---

so **if** the input is **checked** ...

...the `~` make us not styling the input itself, but the **styling what we want** (in this case `span`)

EDIT: make sure that everything you want to style is after the input because the `~` can't select the previous elements.

## here the code

```css
input[type=checkbox]:checked~span {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <label for="1640801145364">
        <input type="checkbox" value="foo" id="1640801145364" name="foo"> 
        <span>foo</span>
    </label>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks you so much for your answer, Laaouatni Anas!